# Differential Equations Solving for y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering whether anyone could help me with a question which I am currently stuck on? It is asking for the general solution for the expression.

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1 {y-3}$$
$$y > 3 ,y(2)=5$$

I have Reciprocated both sides, establishing that 
$$x = \int (y-3)dy$$
 but then it forms a quadratic and I cant seem to find the expression for y. It is probaby really easy I just cant seem to do it, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes it is just not possible or worth the effort to get an explicit solution in terms of $y$

Comment: What quadratic equation have you got? After seperating the variables the equation is $(y-3) \ dy=dx\Rightarrow \int \ (y-3) \ dy=\int \ dx$

Comment: Have you solved the problem by using the hint? If not, give a reply. If yes, give a reply as well.

Comment: @Gobabis It doesn´t take much effort to solve the equation.

Comment: I think what it is asked here is not correct... This a Cauchy problem and not find "a general solution" problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1 {y-3}$$
The differential equation is separable 
$$\int y-3 dy= \int dx$$
$$\frac {y^2}2-3y=x+K$$
$${y^2}-6y=2x+K$$
Complete the square 
$${y^2}-6y+\color{red}{9}=2x+K+\color{red}{9}$$
$$(y-3)^2=2x+C$$
$$y(2)=5 \implies 2^2=4+C \implies C=0$$
Therefore
$$(y-3)^2=2x$$
$$y(x)=3+ \sqrt {2x}$$

Comment: You have just integrated it as $\int(y-3)dy = \frac{(y-3)^2}{2}=x+C$. No need to complete the square.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit different approach:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{y-3}$$
Let $u=y-3$, then we have that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
So
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{u}$$
$$u\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=1$$
$$2u\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=2$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u^2}{\mathrm{d}x}=2$$
$$u^2=2x+C$$
And if we use the initial conditions now:
$$y(2)=u(2)+3=5$$
$$u(2)=2$$
So
$$4=4+C$$
$$C=0$$
Back to the equation:
$$u^2=2x$$
$$u=\sqrt{2x}$$
$$y-3=\sqrt{2x}$$
$$y(x)=\sqrt{2x}+3$$